# Google appmaker how to have a password type input (hidden text)?

Tags: google-app-maker

I want to have a password input as simple as the HTML regular type="password" input (i.e., 
`<input type="password" id="password_field">`). Are there any built in styles (maybe like 'required') that does that? If not how can I have an obfuscated text field?

I was thinking perhaps I could use the HTML widget and add it there but I am not sure how to access the input's value within the HTML widget. I can imagine it can be done with jQuery, but I do not want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code inside the **onAttach** event handler of your TextBox widget:

```
widget.getElement().children[1].setAttribute("type", "password");
widget.getElement().children[1].setAttribute("id", "password_field");
```

Comment: Don't forget to upvote or accept the answer if helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful to know. I can't upvote with my reputation, but the answer sure is good.